# Displaying timezone-formatted date as UTC time

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone, momentjs

on my UI, I try to display a date based on a specific timezone. In this example, I will use Americas/New_York as the timezone. This is how I did it.

```
    $scope.getStartTime = function(){
        var date = new Date();
        return moment(date).tz("Americas/New_York").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    };
```

Afterwards, I want to send this data and send it to my server. In my server however, I want it so that it is always serialized into UTC time instead of in the New York Timezone (EST).

For example, if the time was 12:00 P.M. in New York, then the time would be serialized to 4:00 P.M. in UTC time before it was sent to the backend. This was my attempt:

```
    var date = getStartTime();
    ....
    // Display the date in the UI
    ....
    $scope.revertStartTime(date);

    $scope.revertStartTime = function(startTime) {
        console.log("Start time: ", startTime);
        console.log("Moment: ", moment(startTime).format());
        console.log("Converted to utc time: ", moment().utc(startTime).format());
        return moment.utc(startTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    }
```

I tried to revert the start time by using the `moment().utc()` function and hoped that the date would change to a UTC based date but unfortunately it keeps turning my date into the localized date instead of UTC date and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

Tried to follow the below method and here is what I did:

```
    $scope.getStartTime = function(){
        var date = new Date();
        var startTime = new moment(date).tz($rootScope.userinfo.timeZone).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
        $rootScope.offset = moment().utcOffset(startTime);    
        console.log("offset: ", $rootScope.offset);
        return startTime;
    };

    $scope.revertStartTime = function(startTime) {
        console.log("User Selected Time: ", moment().utcOffset(startTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
        return moment().utcOffset(startTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    }
```

But all I get is an error saying that `revertStartTime` returns an `Invalid Date`.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- Hoping it's a typo, but just to point out, the zone ID is `America/New_York`, not `Americas/New_York`.
- You can pass a value as `moment.utc(foo)`, or `moment(foo).utc()`, but not `moment().utc(foo)`.  The difference is that one interprets the input as UTC and stays in UTC mode, while they other just switches to UTC mode.  You can also think of this as "converting to UTC", but really the underlying timestamp value doesn't change.
- Yes, you can switch to UTC mode and call format, but you can also just call `.toISOString()` regardless of what mode you're in.  That's already in the ISO format you're looking for.
- Note that if you start with a unique point in time, and you end with converting to UTC, no amount of switching time zones or offsets in the middle will change the result.  In other words, these are all equivalent:

  ```
  moment().toISOString()
  moment.utc().toISOString()
  moment(new Date()).toISOString()
  moment.utc(new Date()).toISOString()
  moment(new Date()).utc().toISOString()
  moment().tz('America/New_York').toISOString()
  moment.tz('America/New_York').toISOString()
  moment().utcOffset(1234).toISOString()
  moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')
  moment().utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]')
  ```

  Only the last two even need to be in UTC mode, because the `format` function would produce different output if in local mode or in a particular time zone.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have read your examples and I see what you are saying. I have tried the following: `moment().utcOffset(startTime).toISOString()` where startTime is assigned like so: `startTime = new moment(date).tz("Americas/New_York").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')`. In this way I want to change the `startTime`, whatever it may be (it can be changed because it is a date in a time picker) and convert it into UTC time.  However, the method gives me an `Invalid Date`. Is there any reason why this is so?

Comment: You can't pass that to `utcOffset`.  Offsets are either numeric minutes from UTC, or strings like `"-04:00"`.  I was just trying to illustrate that regardless of what offset you pass it's not going to affect the results of that particular operation.

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?  If `date` is just the current date derived from `new Date()`, then you don't need to supply it.  It's still very unclear what you're asking for.  Are you just saying that you have a string in that format which is new york time and you want the equivalent UTC time in the same format?

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this you'd want to use [`.utcOffset()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc-offset/). It is the preferred method as of Moment 2.9.0. This function uses the real offset from UTC, not the reverse offset (e.g., -240 for New York during DST). Offset strings like "+0400" work the same as before:

```
// always "2013-05-23 00:55"
moment(1369266934311).utcOffset(60).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
moment(1369266934311).utcOffset('+0100').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

The older [`.zone()` as a setter](https://github.com/timrwood/moment/pull/671) was **deprecated** in Moment.js 2.9.0. It accepted a string containing a timezone identifier (e.g., "-0400" or "-04:00" for -4 hours) or a number representing minutes *behind* UTC (e.g., 240 for New York during DST).

```
// always "2013-05-23 00:55"
moment(1369266934311).zone(-60).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
moment(1369266934311).zone('+0100').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

---

To work with named timezones instead of numeric offsets, include [Moment Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) and use `.tz()` instead:

```
// determines the correct offset for America/Phoenix at the given moment
// always "2013-05-22 16:55"
moment(1369266934311).tz('America/Phoenix').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
```

Comment: Ah I see. The bottom line of code works, but actually gives an incorrect offset. As I posted above, my time is in Eastern Standard time. However, my local timezone is in Pacific Standard Time. When I perform the above like so: `moment(startTime).tz('UTC').format()`, my startTime is offsetted by 7 hours (which is what it should be for Pacific Standard Time Zone) instead of 4 hours (which is what it should be for Eastern Standard Time Zone). Would you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @user1871869 - try looking at the following and let me know if that makes sense: http://jsfiddle.net/uq99udc9/4/. If not I'll go in depth a little more - you're almost there!

Comment: Hi, I have looked at your example and I can't seem to figure out how I can do it with my own use case. The reason being is that I am using the time and displaying it on a time picker based on a particular time zone (in my case, EST). On this time picker, a user can change  the time to whatever time he or she would want and then when I click submit, I would then change that time they set on the time picker to UTC time (which would always be +4 hours ahead of the time they set because EST -> UTC time is 4 hour difference. I can't seem to figure that out based on the fiddle above.

Comment: Hey I unfortunately couldn't get it to work. I tried to follow your method but I simply couldn't get it to work. I posted my attempt above. Do you mind making a fiddle for me? Thanks!